# Booting in graphical interface like desktop version

Tags: 14.04

Can I start server in graphical mode or interface

Answer (score 0):

yes should be able to no problem install unity with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` then rweboot to see if it works if not try adding to your /etc/rc.local `unity && startx`